# Is there a way to increase the number of labels to be trained in AutoML natural language processing?

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

Currently in the multilabel classification, the maximum amount of labels that can be trained has been set to 100. Is there any way to increase the number of labels that can be trained?

Answer (score 0):

Update: AutoML Natural Language [just went GA](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/machine-learning-feature-automl-natural-language-generally-available) and now includes support for 5000 (!) labels.